# htaccess reading files from folder (web alias)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have in ROOT folders **root_public**, **root_about**, **root_maps**

and i need to show it to this sample:

- **domain.com** <- everything from _public
- **domain.com/about** AND **domain.com/about/** <- everything from _about
- **domain.com/maps** AND **domain.com/maps/** <- everything from _maps

**but** i don't know, what i will do with root_public\maps .. it could be problem.
so how i can resolve this problem? because i need this structure. and how i can do this?

i am using:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _public/$1 [NC]
```

this to read everything from file _public but i don't know, how to do subfolders!

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I am assuming you have a directory structure that looks like:

```
/your/document/root/_public
/your/document/root/_about
/your/document/root/_maps
```

...where the Apache `DocumentRoot` is `/your/document/root`.

The following would work, though I'm sure there are neater solutions.

```
# add trailing slash to domain.com/about and domain.com/maps
RewriteRule ^/(about|maps)$ /$1/

# rewrite domain.com/about/something to /_about/something
RewriteRule ^/(about|maps)/(.*) /_$1/$2

# rewrite anything that doesn't start about/ or maps/ to _public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(about|maps)/
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /_public/$1
```